# Which memory does Cassandra use for Row Cache?

Tags: java, configuration, cassandra, heap-memory

Does it use the heap memory or the remaining server memory?

I have a server with 32 GB of RAM, I initialised Cassandra with a 25 GB MAX_HEAP_SIZE and I specified a Row Cache capacity of 20 GB.

Am I correctly assuming Row Cache uses the heap memory I initialised the process with? Or is my configuration expecting the server to have at least 45 GB of ram?

Comment: Just curious: Any GC problems with that much heap (recommended max is 8G)?

Comment: None so far, but I'll keep an eye on it and report back if there are

Comment: @DirkLachowski, according to [omnibear's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17884500/1782) my setup is wrong and bound to blow up anyway, so I'm going to have to change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This row key documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html#cassandra/operations/../configuration/../operations/../configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__row_cache_provider) states that there are 2 actual row_cache_provider implementations:

> SerializingCacheProvider: Serializes the contents of the row and
>   stores it in native memory, that is, **off the JVM Heap**

and

> ConcurrentLinkedHashCacheProvider: Rows are cached **using the JVM heap**, 
>   providing the same row cache behavior as Cassandra versions prior to 0.8.

The default is *SerializingCacheProvider* so if you don't change it, row cache does not use the JVM Heap memory.

Comment: I am asking about *Row Cache*, not *Key Cache*

Comment: Fair enough. I revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Much better thanks! Your conclusion is wrong though, by default row cache is not part of the heap

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and improving my answer. The default implementation is the SerializingCacheProvider and thus, off the JVM heap. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, the row cache is an `ICache`, which is put onto the heap as per its being an object without special treatment.

You may perform further tests to ascertain the true performance and memory handling.